# In the context of ANNs, is there multi-task learning iff the network has more than 1 output?

Tags: neural-networks, terminology, multitask-learning

This is a terminology question: in the context of artificial neural networks,
does [multi-task learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-task_learning) occur iff the network has more than 1 output?

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple outputs is necessary but not sufficient for multi-task learning.

One task could be a multi-label classification task (e.g. is the input a picture of a human, a cat or a dog?) with one output node per target class. So a network with three outputs is performing a single task.

A second related task could be to predict what time of day the input photo was taken (e.g. morning, afternoon or night). So a multi-task network here could have six outputs defining the two tasks.

Comment: Thanks. In the case of the multi classification human, a cat or a dog, couldn't one argue that therr are three different tasks: task 1 is it a picture of a human? Task 2 is it a picture of a cat? Etc

Answer (score 0):

The multiple tasks in *multi-task learning* may not be explicitly distinct classes, but differing distributions of the same labels. For example, the following could all be considered multi-task learning frameworks:

| Framework | Input | Output | Single task interpretation | Multi-task interpretation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Multi-class classification | Image | Cat, dog, fish | What animal is this? | Is this a cat? Is this a dog? Is this a fish? |
| Binary classification | Text | Spam, not spam | Is this email spam? | Is this English email spam? Is this Spanish email spam? Is this Russian email spam? |

Or more explicitly, the multiple tasks may be different labels on the same underlying data (multi-label classification). Explicitly one can build a multiheaded model, where the backbone is shared amongst related (or indeed unrelated) tasks, and the heads correspond to the different tasks e.g:

| Framework | Shared backbone | Input | Output | Task |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Multi-headed | "High level" facial features | Image | **Head 1:** binary classification **Head 2:** multi-class classification **Task 3:** regression | **Task 1:** Is this a man or a woman? **Task 2:** What ethnicity is this person? **Task 3:** How old is this person? |